# hg clone aborts reporting that it can't find .hg/store/lock in the repository

Tags: mercurial

I created a repository on a remote machine using:

```
    hg init

    hg add

    hg commit
```

The repository was created.

I cloned the repository on a local machine with no errors reported;  The files seem to be there

Now I'm trying to make a clone of the clone (as a working copy) using:

```
    hg clone "path to original clone"
```

It returns:

destination directory: "name of repository"

abort: No such file or directory: "path to original clone"/.hg/store/lock

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could you list the concrete commands in sequence, so one can try to reproduce?

Comment: Do you add files with hg add? If so, nothing special about them? Have you tried just creating an empty repository, and cloning that (to verify that the problem occurs in this case as well)?

Comment: Which version of Mercurial are you using?

Comment: The original repository was generated on a remote machine using 1.3.1 using: hg init in an existing directory; hg add; hg commit

Comment: The clone was made on my local machine using 1.7.5 using: hg clone "path to remote repository"

Comment: I tried to create a local "working clone" using 1.7.5 using: hg clone "path the local clone"

Comment: Mecurial aborts, complaining "No such file or directory: 'path to local clone'/.hg/store/lock

Comment: If I look into the directory structure of the local clone, I see the .hg directory, and the store directory, but there is no file named "lock"...      Is this a permissions issue?   Or do I need to put something in a .hgrc or Mercurial.ini file?  The local machine is a Windows machine...

Comment: I also created an empty repository in the same area as the "cloned" repository.   I was able to clone this one.   I assume that I can clone a cloned repository.   Is there a problem in cloning a repository that was cloned from a remote machine that is using a different version of mercurial?

Comment: No, you can clone any older repo just fine.

Comment: [~/Temp/VLSI/HG_Repositories]-> hg clone --debug --traceback /cygdrive/s/HG_Repositories/Valu
destination directory: Valu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 58, in _runcatch
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 593, in _dispatch
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 401, in runcommand

Comment: File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 644, in _runcommand
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 598, in checkargs
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 591, in <lambda>
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 426, in check
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 736, in clone
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 272, in clone

Comment: File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 757, in lock
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 734, in _lock
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/lock.py", line 38, in __init__
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/lock.py", line 56, in lock
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/lock.py", line 80, in trylock
  File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/lock.py", line 99, in testlock

Comment: File "usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 594, in readlock
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/cygdrive/s/HG_Repositories/Valu/.hg/store/lock'
abort: No such file or directory: /cygdrive/s/HG_Repositories/Valu/.hg/store/lock

Comment: Is it possible that ~/Temp/VLSI/HG_Repositories is the same location as cygdrive/s/HG_Repositories?  If so, you're cloning the repo into itself and need to provide a destination name.

Comment: Apparently, judging by the traceback, when hg first tries to create /cygdrive/s/HG_Repositories/Valu/.hg/store/lock, an OSError is raised with errno == EEXIST (on line 76 of mercurial/lock.py). Then, when hg tries to read the ostensibly existing lock, it turns out to not exist! Hence, something isn't quite right in this scenario. I also suggest you try to provide another destination name for your new clone.

Comment: /cygdrive/s is a different volume (network drive).   Attempting to create "Working" clone on "C" drive of local machine.   Tried adding a destination name...  Same result...

Comment: Could be a cygwin anomaly, have you tried creating the remote repo with hg 1.7.5 though? Just to rule out version incompatibility.

Comment: Mercurial on the remote host has been updated to 1.7.5.      It also fails if I try to do "hg pull" (on the local machine)...  Same message...

Answer (score 3):

What filesystem is used on the partition where the main repository is ?

Actually, when Mercurial is doing some operations, it needs to lock the repository. For doing this it creates a symbolic link to an nonexistent file, when the filesystem supports it, in the .hg repository, telling every other processes that the repository can't be modified at this time. When symbolic links aren't supported by the filesystem, a normal file is created.

However, there's some problems with some FUSE filesystems, typically SSHFS with the follow_symlinks option activated. FUSE reports that he knows about symbolic links, but since SSHFS follows the symbolic link and the file doesn't exist, the "state" of the link is marked as unknown thus Mercurial thinks the repository isn't correctly locked and abort the operation.

I see you're using Cygwin, so maybe it's the same kind of problem with tools designed for UNIX on a windows filesystem. It's a strange, coworkers of mine are using Mercurial via Cygwin just fine.

I don't know if it's the case for you, but I lost nearly half a day on this problem. Maybe this answers can help some people in the future.

Comment: The Local repository is hosted on a network file system (Buffalo Technology Terastation).    I just tried to do a "hg pull" to update the local repository (from the remote one) and got the same message!!

Comment: I think I see a potential problem...   As a test, I tried to create a symbolic link manually in the directory that hosts the local repository (on the network drive).   In that directory, I did "ln -s aaa bbb"  and a link was created, but it's name was "bbb.lnk" (versus just bbb).    So I looked into .hg/store of the repository that I was trying to "pull" to and there was a file named "lock.lnk".   So, is there a way to tell mercurial that the link name has a suffix of .lnk???

Answer (score 1):

Please paste in the actual command that's failing and the output including the actual path to the clone that you're cloning.  When you do the clone use `--debug` and `--traceback` too.

As a workaround you can can always try `hg init newclone` followed by `hg pull -R newclone pathtooriginalclone`, which is effectively equivalent except it doesn't use local hardlinks when possible.

Comment: Thanks... work-around works...  Still curious as to why simple clone doesn't work...    Thanks again